# How to change the url the core search form submits to?

Tags: search

The action value for the core search form is /search/node.

How could I get it to go instead to a different url for a custom View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to do it with code you can use [Custom Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_search)it gives you the possibility to configure it from configuration page:
For node search you can change it from ***admin/config/search/pages/manage/node_search***

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.8.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.8.x) to alter a form.

Core's search block form has a form id of *search_block_form*, so you could implement with *hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()* like:

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

function mymodule_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#action'] = '/my-custom-path';
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you may want to create a custom block with a simple form to submit to your other url.

Comment: Thanks so much @sonfd. That's a great help.

Comment: Further question: do you happen to know how I can pass a search word in the url to an exposed filter in a view? I looked for an answer but could not find one. I am trying to use a Search API view with exposed filter for search term, as the search results page.

Comment: @EdwardPeters - This is a totally different question. You should ask a new one.